# Can nuxt 3 rewrite url with sub directory

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have project structure like this

```
- pages
 - login.vue
 - index.vue
 auth
 - about.vue
```

by default, nuxt can access a path with 'localhost:3000/' and it will rendered by /pages/index.vue

in case if i want to access a page in dir auth/about it's must be access a path
'localhost:3000/auth/about'

but i want to access path with 'localhost:3000/about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [page alias](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/pages/#alias) if you want to have another entry point

```html
<script setup>
definePageMeta({
  alias: ['/about']
})
</script>

<template>
  <div>this is an auth page</div>
</template>
```

So that the following file structure

[image]

could be accessed via either `/about` or `/auth/about`.

Comment: Thanks in advance, so do you have any suggestion about structure like this ?

Comment: @Thee Not sure which kind of suggestion do you expect here since I have no idea about your app. Having pages in the `pages` directory is totally fine for me, never felt the need to change that.

Comment: Is it possible to also do this with a dynamic route?